# Prolog Working Mechanism

Tags: prolog

I am quite new to Prolog. I have read a lot of documents and checked examples.

I have a code, simplified version could be seen below;

```
go :-
    write('Patient Name? '),
    read(Patient),
    case(Patient,Disorder),
    write_list([Patient,' has', ' ', Disorder,'.']),nl.

go :-
    write('No diagnosis'),nl.

statement(Patient,fever) :-
    write_list([Patient,has fever (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

statement(Patient,itch) :-
    write_list([Patient,has itch (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

statement(Patient,headache) :-
    write_list([Patient,'has headache(y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

statement(Patient,cough) :-
    write_list([Patient,' has cough (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

case(Patient,pt_measles) :-
    statement(Patient,fever),
    statement(Patient,itch).

case(Patient,pt_german_measles) :-
    statement(Patient,fever),
    statement(Patient,itch),
    statement(Patient,headache).

write_list([]).
write_list([A| Z]) :-
    write(A),
    write_list(Z).

response(Reply) :-
    get_single_char(Code),
    put_code(Code), nl,
    char_code(Reply, Code).
```

Code asks me about patient name and statements. What I am struggling on is, it asks me questions with order of `fever? -> itch? -> headache? ->cough?`. If I select No for itch, it skips headache and cough question and jumps to new case. How does it skip headache and cough without asking the question to new case, or what makes it jump to new case without asking these questions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Prolog, if you have two queries, separated by a comma, such as `p1, p2, ...` then if `p1` fails, it will not move on to test `p2` but rather it will backtrack. In this case, in the statements, `statement(Patient, itch), statement(Patient, headache)` it will not check `statement(Patient, headache)` if `statement(Patient, itch)` fails. You aren't showing the logic for `cough` but I suspect it's the same scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification, yes cough has the same scenario. By the way, response returns me an ascii value of input, how does it determine whether it is pressed on 'y'? Thanks in advance!